# Can we Add .pug files to magento 2.4 instead of blocks?

Tags: magento2

Can we Add .pug files to magento 2.4 instead of blocks ?
I've tried and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Answer **No, Its not possible**

You can use `.html` or `.phtml` file instead of `.pug`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 200% sure but I don't think so, the whole system is made to work with phtml and html. When I started I would have like to get twig too; I though it was possible as Magento as some basis with symfony.

Now may be you can customize the renderers to make it possible ? I guess it's possible but it's a lot of work for sure.